# Tiles apache not work with Spring MVC

Tags: apache, jsp, spring-mvc

I first using tiles apache and I have small problem, because website can not see titles apache. Below are sources. I did like here [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9244FjHT2M&list=PLmcxdcWPhFqMq2BctGktOcIJKUw23wJeh&index=5)

**CarController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**general.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/layout/classic.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="index" extends="common">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Java Blog agragator" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**classic.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title"></tiles:getAsString></title>
</head>
<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <center><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**footer.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

&copy; Author
```

**servler-context.xml**

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-request-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change servlet-context.xml in

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">

            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In the pom delete other tiles dependencies and add ONLY the below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**classic.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <title>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="title">
        </tiles:insertAttribute>
    </title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
    <footer>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

**general.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/layout/classic.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Not Found" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="index" extends="common">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Java Blog agragator" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Hope this is of help